# How to avoid missing assembly reference when project .shared.cs code from web to silverlight project

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I started learning silverlight a few day ago. I'm following the Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4 book.

Today I encountered a problem when i build the entire solution. (holding the silverlight and the web project) I added a simple calculated field to the web project using a partial class with the .shared.cs extension.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BusinessApplication1.Web
{
    public partial class Product
    {
        public decimal ProfitMargi
        {
            get { return ListPrice - StandardCost; }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I build this solution, this partial class is copied to the silverlight project where i get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

on:

```
using System.Web;
```

I cannot remove this reference from the file because it's write protected and it will be overwritten the next time i build again.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you missing the assembly reference containing that namespace?

Comment: Yes, it is missing, but when i try to add it, i get the

You can't add a reference to System.Web.dll as it was not built against the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight projects will only work with Silverlight assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on this, but IIRC you cannot use some assemblies, such as System.Web.dll, inside of Silverlight projects because they are not supported in the Silverlight version of the .NET Framework. I could be wrong on this, but I seem to recall having a similar issue when working with Silverlight and realising I couldn't use some of the functionality within .NET that I would have liked.

From having a look around on Google, a lot of people seem to be saying you use System.Web.Silverlight.dll instead of System.Web.dll. See [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/157359.aspx/1) for some information on that.

Comment: I can't find the System.Web.Silverlight in the SDK. But i found i could just remove this line 'using System.Web' on server side (where i do have write permission to this file) because i don't need it neither on client or server side. But i hope i will not need this in the feature...